# Listen to 'file to other file' drag-and-drop on windows desktop

Tags: c#, windows, shell

I would like to create drag-and-drop folder creation for windows desktop in C#, kind of like android, where you can drop two apps onto eachother, which will create a folder.

Is there a way to listen to the event of one shortcut or file being placed on another, and receiving information about both of those files?